# Not able to get gallery app intent

Tags: android

```
private static Intent galleryIntent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,     Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY);
```

I am not able to get the gallery intent, eclipse says that makeMainSelectorActivity is not defined. How exactly does makeMainSelectorActivity work?

Comment: Got the answer. Its supported from API level 15. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that only works for API 15 or higher.  I had to add this to the manifest, and it works (for API 15 or higher):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Another option is (in my case open a calendar but it is similar):

```
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        Intent calendar = openCalendar();
    } else{Intent calendar2 = new Intent();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar",
                "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
        calendar2.setComponent(cn);
    }

@TargetApi(15)
private Intent openCalendar(){
    return Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(
            Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR);
}
```

In the last way you can use any version in the manifest.